# Send radio box value with $_POST

Tags: php, html, forms, post, radio-button

How can I send a radio or checkbox value to the $_POST array even when the field is empty?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST)) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_POST);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
?>

<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="radio" name="gender">

    <input type="submit"> 
</form>
```

Here is what I get from the page if I hit submit without even filling out data.

```
Array
(
    [name] => 
    [email] => 
)
```

As you see, without touching the input type text, their value was pushed to the $_POST array. How can I do this with the radio box? I essentially want to "set" it, although it is blank just like the text inputs.

I know I could always call

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['gender'])) {
     //Code
  }
?>
```

But that's not necessarily what I'm looking for. I need it to set automatically. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this it will work :**

`Unchecked radio` elements are not submitted as they are not considered as `successful`. So you have to check if they are sent using the `isset` or `empty` function.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST)) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_POST);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
?>

<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="1"/>Male
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like it only added the "submit" item to the $_POST array. I got the results
`
Array
(
    [name] => 
    [email] => 
    [submit] => submit
)
`

Comment: @xToxikx, You only get the value of `checked` radio in the `$_POST` array. I edited my answer. I hope it will help you.

Comment: ahh okay gotcha, I was trying to avoid this because I don't want to just assume a user is a specific gender but it looks like this may be the only option. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Should be :

HTML :

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"/>Test
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

PHP Code :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    echo $radio_value = $_POST["radio"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example:

```
// Set a default value as male
<input type="radio" name="gender" checked value="male"> Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="femail"> Female
```

and you will get the value

```
Array
(
    [name] => 
    [email] => 
    [gender]=>male
)
```

You only get the `checked` radio in the `$_POST` array

Comment: Yeah I actually looked into this earlier and got it to work. That is one option, the only problem is we're assuming the user is 'male' or 'female' automatically. Just kind of an aesthetic thing but maybe I'll just have to make that sacrifice. Thanks!

Comment: @xToxikx, you can't get radio button value without `checked` property in the `$_POST` array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send blank value automatically then
By default checked that radio button and set blank value:

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">

<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="radio" name="gender" value='' checked>

<input type="submit"> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML :
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="radio" name="gender" checked  value="male"/>Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/>Female
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

PHP :
 if(isset($_POST)) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="radio" name="gender" checked value="male"> Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="femail"> Female
<input type="submit" value="submit"> 
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST)) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
    echo '</pre>';
}
?>
```